# Add Calculation Field To Report

Tags: ms-access, report, ms-access-2013, calculation

I am running access 2013, with a linked view from SQL Server 2008 R2.  I have two fields that I want to sum and data types are:

> SQL Server 2008: Decimal(10,2)
>   Access: Number

They are being formatted in my query to currency using this syntax:

```
cf1: Format([calcfield1],"Currency")
cf2: Format([calcfield2],"Currency")
```

I have a report with both of these fields bound to text boxes and am adding a 3rd textbox to `SUM()` them.  This is the control source syntax I input to `SUM()` the fields:

```
Name: SumOfFields
Control Source: =Sum([cf1]+[cf2])
```

Now when I attempt to view the access 2013 form, I get the error message displayed below.  What do I need to change in order to perform this calculation on my report?
[image: Error Message]

**EDIT**
If it makes a difference one `cf1` is in the `Serial Header` section of my report, and the field `cf2` is in the `Details` section of my report, and can have multiple entries.  I want the `SUM()` that I am trying to add to be added to the `Details` section of the report like below:

```
Serial Header
$22.40
Details
$10.00
$13.40
$10.20

$56.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the link here it may help.  A few things come to mind to check, but with the limited info this is the best I can do...

> 1) One of the fields is in a custom header which would mean that the total you are attempting to add needs to be in the custom footer
>   2) You need to place the total in the footer of the report

[Link](http://www.jegsworks.com/lessons/databases/formsreports/step-totals-simple.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @user2676140 - the total should appear in the group footer and should probably look something like:

```
=[cf1] + Sum([cf2])
```

If this doesn't work then I would try taking the `Format` wrapper off `[cf1]` and `[cf2]` and use the controls' properties to format them as Currency. Then maybe have the `ControlSource` for `SumOfFields` as

```
=[calcfield1] + Sum([calcfield2])
```

Again, use the properties of `SumOfField` to set the format.